# How do I know if my Google Talk conversations in Empathy is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, empathy

In Ubuntu 14.04, my Google Talk account integration is now part of the Ubuntu's Online Accounts. I don't see any "URLs" or mentioning of the protocols that it's using. How do I know if my conversation going through Empathy's GTalk plug-in is encrypted?

Comment: Unless both sides talking are using the encryption plugin, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Technically since you'll never be able to be sure about what's happening on the other side, meaning what software/hardware or whatever is used, let alone the chance of malware being around on yours or theirs computer, you can't be 100% sure that the conversation is encrypted and/or that the connection is not interfered with.

On the other hand if you use reasonably safe software like Ubuntu you may assume that there might be a certain degree of trust.

As always it's up to you what you trust and what you don't trust and if possible issues are worth worrying about.